# How to collect several interfaces into a Collection in HK2?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, hk2

I have my `AbstractBinder` and I bind several classes with the same interface. Let's say I bind `Fish` and `Cat` which both implement `Animal` interface.

What is the easiest/proper way of injecting them into a bean which takes `Collection<Animal>` ?

PS: Spring has equivalent in simply `@Autowire List<Animal>` and the collection is created and populated by Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HK2 has [`IterableProvider<T>`](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html), as mentioned [here in the documentation](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/introduction.html#IterableProvider). You can get the service [by name](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html#named%28java.lang.String%29), by [qualifier annotation](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html#qualifiedWith%28java.lang.annotation.Annotation...%29), or just iterate over them, as it's an `Iterable`. Just for fun, here is a test.

```
public class IterableProviderTest {
    
    public static interface Service {}
    
    public static class ServiceOne implements Service {}
    
    @QualAnno
    public static class ServiceTwo implements Service {}
    
    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface QualAnno {
        public static class Instance 
                extends AnnotationLiteral<QualAnno> implements QualAnno {
            public static QualAnno get() {
                return new Instance();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(ServiceOne.class).to(Service.class).named("one");
            bind(ServiceTwo.class).to(Service.class).qualifiedBy(QualAnno.Instance.get());
        }  
    }
    
    @Inject
    private IterableProvider<Service> services;
    
    @Test
    public void test_IterableProvider() {
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new Binder());
        locator.inject(IterableProviderTest.this);
        
        assertEquals(2, services.getSize());
        
        Service serviceOne = services.named("one").get();
        assertTrue(serviceOne instanceof ServiceOne);
        
        Service serviceTwo = services.qualifiedWith(QualAnno.Instance.get()).get();
        assertTrue(serviceTwo instanceof ServiceTwo);  
    }
}
```

---

#### UPDATE

For a `List<Service>` (to avoid HK2 InterablProvider), the only think I can think of is to use a `Factory` and inject the `IterableProvider` into it, and from there return the list. For example

```
public class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        ...
        bindFactory(ListServiceFactory.class).to(new TypeLiteral<List<Service>>(){});
    }  
}

public static class ListServiceFactory implements Factory<List<Service>> {
    
    @Inject
    private IterableProvider<Service> services;

    @Override
    public List<Service> provide() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(services);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(List<Service> t) {}
}
```

Yeah it's a little bit of extra work.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Isn't it a bit weird that your pojo will contain `IterableProvider<...>` which is HK2 specific? If I'm writing a unit test for example I would need to mock that somehow ...

Comment: Ah, it extends `Iterable` ... ok then. Still don't like the HK2 specific reference though.

Comment: The extra functionality like narrowing down the selection is cool though :D

Comment: Maybe there's another way, but the only think I can think of is if you really do not want the IterableProvider, is to use a Factory and inject the IterableProvider there and in turn return a Collection. But there you lose the functionality of the IterableProvider :-)

Comment: We have debated allowing people to just @Inject Iterable.  Trouble is it *could* be interfered with by a Factory producing Iterable.  Still, I agree it might be nice to have the pojo be completely without hk2 references

Comment: I just met that. Have my bean constructor parameter with `IterableProvide` and in unit tests I need to provide mock. Which is extra work :)

Comment: Maybe a helper would be nice `static <T> IterarableProvider<T>.of(T... elements)` for tests?

Answer (score 3):

In the latest release of hk2 (2.4.0) you can

`@Inject Iterable<Foo> foos;`

That allows you to keep your pojo's without any hk2 API in them.

For more information see: [Iterable Injection](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0/introduction.html#Iterable_injection)

Comment: Is this `Iterable<Foo>` syntax supposed to work for constructor injection as well?

Comment: Yes.  If it does not please enter a bug!