# Testing Jersey app, Injecting classes using Jersey Injection built-in framework (HK2)

Tags: java, testing, dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

I need to create tests for some class. This class in main project (`src/main/java/..`) is injected easily into another classes, since I have custom ResourceConfig class which declares which packages have to be scanned to seek for service classes.

Now I created test directories (in `src/test/java/..`) and created a class, something like:

```
public class TheMentionedClassIntegrationTest {
    @Inject
    private TheMentionedClass theMentionedClass ;

    @Test
    public void testProcessMethod() {
        assertNotNull(theMentionedClass);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that whatever I do the class is always null. In another tests in the project I was using `JerseyTest` class. So I tried to do the same here, extend `TheMentionedClassIntegrationTest` with `JerseyTest`, override `configure` method, create my private `ResourceConfig` class which registers `Binder` (default for whole project) and register `TheMentionedClassIntegrationTest` as well.

It didnt work. I did many different attempts but none of them were successfull. I think working with `HK2` is extremly difficult, there is no good documentation or so..

Do you guys have an idea how to inject TheMentionedClass into the test class? Maybe my approach is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for hk2 is at http://hk2.java.net.  If there is need for more or better documentation please tell us what is missing and what you would like to see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to just create the `ServiceLocator` and use it to inject the test class, as see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34022639/2587435). For example

```
public class TheMentionedClassIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    private TheMentionedClass theMentionedClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new YourBinder());
        locator.inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessMethod() {
        assertNotNull(theMentionedClass);
    }
}
```

You could alternatively use (make) a JUnit runner, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794011/2587435).

For some other ideas, you might want to check out the tests for the [hk2-testing](https://github.com/hk2-project/hk2), and all of its containing projects for some use case examples.

Comment: your answer should be added to the official documentation.. thanks!!